# Why do I get 'addon not found' errors when starting blender from the command line?

Tags: error, command-line

I installed blender with the source code and when I start from the command line it shows:

```
addon not found: 'io_scene_3ds'
addon not found: 'io_scene_fbx'
addon not found: 'io_anim_bvh'
addon not found: 'io_mesh_ply'
addon not found: 'io_scene_obj'
addon not found: 'io_scene_x3d'
addon not found: 'io_mesh_stl'
addon not found: 'io_mesh_uv_layout'
addon not found: 'io_curve_svg'
addon not found: 'object_boolean_tools'
addon not found: 'space_view3d_pie_menus'
addon not found: 'render_auto_tile_size'
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: How did you 'install Blender with the source code'? What does that mean? Do you mean you compiled Blender from the source code and then run it? Blender Stack Exchange might not be the right place to troubleshoot compiling problems. It's more for questions about the usage of official Blender versions. Try [devtalk forums](https://devtalk.blender.org/) for help with compiling or [download the official release](https://www.blender.org/download/)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're missing some of the addons, which Blender expects to find but can't. Some of them are available as their own source package, and generally are located in the [version]/scripts/addons directory. Compiling from source may have skipped some of those, as they are technically their own subprogram.

They aren't essential for Blender to run, but provide useful services; without UV Layout, as an example, you won't be able to export a UV-unwrap as a 2D graphic. It's been a while since I compiled the program myself, but it's possible that it simply failed during the portion meant to build these—like a missing dependency, as an example—and it just kept going with what it could build. You can find and build many of them independently and simply drop them in that folder.

If you still have the stdout from the build, you may find a hint as to what's missing in there. I hope this helps you.